# Using CSS to center flex elements regardless of screen size

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Question Summary: I cannot figure out why the images on my webpage are only centered when the screen is smaller vs on my desktop, where the images are left-aligned.

Question Body: I am building a website using HTML and CSS for the first time, and while I'm taking lots of tutorials and reading resources, I am still confused on the concept of flex items. On my current website, I have three images horizontally lined up and they are centered when I view the page on a laptop. However, when I view it on my larger desktop, all of the images are left-aligned. I have scoured dozens of pages here about centering items in CSS but nothing is making sense so far -- that may be due to my own naivety with using CSS and HTML, however. I've posted my CSS and HTML code below. Do I have something in this code that is incorrectly left-aligning the images when I expand the screen? (Note: this is my first question on Stack Overflow and while I've read the guidelines for posting questions, I would love any feedback you have on how I can make this clearer). Thank you! (Also, FYI, since it's my first post I am not allowed to embed images yet, or else I would have screenshots of what I'm talking about).

```css
/* Box Model */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Containers */

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container.\31 25\25 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100em;
  min-width: 80em;
}

.container.\37 5\25 {
  width: 60em;
}

.container.\35 0\25 {
  width: 40em;
}

.container.\32 5\25 {
  width: 20em;
}

.container {
  width: 80em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {
  .container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100em;
    min-width: 80em;
  }
  .container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 60em;
  }
  .container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 40em;
  }
  .container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 20em;
  }
  .container {
    width: 80em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 81.25em;
    min-width: 65em;
  }
  .container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 48.75em;
  }
  .container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 32.5em;
  }
  .container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 16.25em;
  }
  .container {
    width: 65em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 112.5%;
    min-width: 90%;
  }
  .container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 67.5%;
  }
  .container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 22.5%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 112.5%;
    min-width: 90%;
  }
  .container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 67.5%;
  }
  .container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 22.5%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 90% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container.\31 25\25 {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 112.5%;
    min-width: 90%;
  }
  .container.\37 5\25 {
    width: 67.5%;
  }
  .container.\35 0\25 {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .container.\32 5\25 {
    width: 22.5%;
  }
  .container {
    width: 90% !important;
  }
}


/* Flex */

.flex {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.flex.flex-2 {
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex.flex-2 article {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .flex.flex-2 article {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    auto
  }
  .flex.flex-2 article:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    auto
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .flex.flex-2 br {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Box */

.box {
  border: solid 1px #dbdbdb;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

.box> :last-child,
.box> :last-child> :last-child,
.box> :last-child> :last-child> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.box.alt {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box.person {
  border: solid 1px #8dcca9;
  padding: 3em 1.5em;
}

.box.person h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.box.person .image {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.box.person .image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<section id="main" class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <header class="align-center">
      <h2>A comprehensive collection of workshops, webinars, and resources for Belmont Forum researchers</h2>
    </header>

    <section id="three" class="wrapper align-center">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="flex flex-2">
          <article>
            <div class="w3-circle">
              <img src="images/globe.jpg" alt="Pic 02" />
            </div>
            <header>
              <h3>By Country/Region</h3>
            </header>
            <footer>
              <a href="Data_Management_Trainings.md" target="_blank" class="button">Find Resources</a>
            </footer>
          </article>
          <article>
            <div class="w3-circle">
              <img src="images/computer.jpg" alt="Pic 01" />
            </div>
            <header>
              <h3>By Resource Type</h3>
            </header>
            <footer>
              <a href="http://bfe-inf.org/sites/default/files/doc-repository/Outline_Data_Skills_Curricula_Framework.pdf" target=_blank " class="button ">Find Resources</a>
       </footer>
      </article>
      <article>
       <div class="w3-circle ">
        <img src="images/business_woman.jpg " alt="globe " />
       </div>
       <header>
        <h3>By Role</h3>
       </header>
       <footer>
        <a href="http://bfe-inf.org/sites/default/files/doc-repository/Outline_Data_Skills_Curricula_Framework.pdf " target=_blank" class="button">Find Resources</a>
            </footer>
          </article>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Your `.flex .flex-2` div is left aligned because its parent div `.inner` is rendering its contents from left to right (which is the default behaviour of a block element) & your div is bound to a specific width.
Flexbox is all about using parent containers to align their children elements - `justify-content` & `align-items` can be used to center your elements from a parent element. :)

Comment: Thank you @Sarahshuffle! A quick clarification question: within the section of the HTML above, <div class = "inner"> is below <section id="three" class="wrapper align-center">. Does that "wrapper align-center" also affect how the flex items are rendering?

Comment: in theory it has the ability to affect them, but in this particular case it has no effect as no styles seem to be attached to those classnames.

Comment: Thanks @Sarahshuffle! This makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand your question. So I tried this out.
Hope it helps!

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#table {
  padding: 3em;
}
#table h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
#table input[name="tcol"],
#table nav {
  display: none;
}
#table h2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#table nav {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
#table nav > label {
  color: #339bf0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}
#table table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
#table table td,
#table table th {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
}
#table table tbody > tr > td h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.05em;
  text-align: center;
}
#table table tfoot > tr > td {
  text-align: center;
}
#table table.data-table.two-col td,
#table table.data-table.two-col th {
  width: 50%;
}
#table table.data-table.three-col td,
#table table.data-table.three-col th {
  width: 33.33%;
}
#table table.data-table.four-col td,
#table table.data-table.four-col th {
  width: 25%;
}
#table table.data-table.five-col td,
#table table.data-table.five-col th {
  width: 20%;
}
#table table.data-table.six-col td,
#table table.data-table.six-col th {
  width: 16.67%;
}
#table table.data-table.seven-col td,
#table table.data-table.seven-col th {
  width: 14.29%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  #table {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  #table h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  #table nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  #table table th,
  #table table td {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #table table.data-table[class*="-col"] th,
  #table table.data-table[class*="-col"] td {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ nav label:nth-of-type(1) {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    color: black;
  }
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ table tr > td:nth-of-type(1),
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ table tr > th:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ nav label:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    color: black;
  }
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ table tr > td:nth-of-type(2),
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ table tr > th:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ nav label:nth-of-type(3) {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    color: black;
  }
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ table tr > td:nth-of-type(3),
  #table input:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ table tr > th:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <h2>A comprehensive collection of workshops, webinars, and resources for Belmont Forum researchers</h2>
  <input id="tcol1" name="tcol" type="radio" checked/>
  <input id="tcol2" name="tcol" type="radio" />
  <input id="tcol3" name="tcol" type="radio" />
  <nav>
    <label for="tcol1">Region</label>
    <label for="tcol2">Type</label>
    <label for="tcol3">Role</label>
  </nav>
  <table class="data-table">
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="images/globe.jpg" alt="Pic 02" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/computer.jpg" alt="Pic 01" /></td>
        <td><img src="images/business_woman.jpg" alt="globe" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>By Country/Region</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>By Resource Type</h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3>By Role</h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3><a href="Data_Management_Trainings.md" target ="_blank" class="button">Find Resources</a></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3><a href="http://bfe-inf.org/sites/default/files/doc-repository/Outline_Data_Skills_Curricula_Framework.pdf" target="_blank" class="button">Find Resources</a></h3>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h3><a href="http://bfe-inf.org/sites/default/files/doc-repository/Outline_Data_Skills_Curricula_Framework.pdf" target="_blank" class="button">Find Resources</a></h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting -- I hadn't thought to format it as a table! For this particular website it looks like a table wouldn't be what I need, but this is great to know for the future as I keep building. Thank you @Erika_Mac!

Comment: That's the [Original Pen](https://codepen.io/augur/pen/QygvGd). Feel free to edit it. If you think that the answer above was useful, please vote up. Hope it helped you!

Comment: Since I don't have a high enough reputation yet, it recorded the upvote but doesn't display it publicly. Once I hit 15!

Comment: Thanks anyway! And keep on practicing!